# Using a Case statment inside a Select query to get multiple types.- getting an expression error

Tags: sql, subquery, expression, case-statement

Am trying to place a case statement inside a sub query which will allow me to display multiple options depending on which condition is being met.

So far I have wrote something like

```
(SELECT A.ValueOne, B.Value2, C.Value3
    CASE 
        WHEN A.ValueOne = 0 THEN 'HELLO'
        WHEN A.ValueOne = 1 THEN 'GOOD BYE' 
        WHEN B.Value2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'GOOD MORNING'
        WHEN C.Value3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'GOOD EVENING'
        END 
    FROM TableD D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableE E ON D.ID = E.TableDID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A ON E.TableEID = B.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableF ON D.ID = TableF.TableDID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableG G ON B.TableGID = G.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableH H ON TableF.TableHID = TableH.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC C ON H.TableC = C.ID
    WHERE D.ID = TableD.ID) 
    AS [Greeting Type],
```

The problem is am getting an error saying I can only use a single expression in the select list.

Am not sure my code above is even valid, am just experimenting, my question is, is there a way to achieve this

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It may be a typo, but you are missing a comma after `C.Value3`

Comment: Hi, Yep that was just a typo, thanks anyways for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a subquery in a context where a scalar subquery is expected.  A scalar subquery can return one column and at most one row.  Presumably, you want the output of the `case` statement.  If so, this should do what you want:

```
(SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN A.ValueOne = 0 THEN 'HELLO'
        WHEN A.ValueOne = 1 THEN 'GOOD BYE' 
        WHEN B.Value2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'GOOD MORNING'
        WHEN C.Value3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'GOOD EVENING'
        END 
    FROM TableD D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableE E ON D.ID = E.TableDID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A ON E.TableEID = B.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableF ON D.ID = TableF.TableDID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableG G ON B.TableGID = G.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableH H ON TableF.TableHID = TableH.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC C ON H.TableC = C.ID
    WHERE D.ID = TableD.ID) 
    AS [Greeting Type],
```

Note that after running this query, you will probably get an error saying that you have more than one row in the result set.  You can fix that by using `top` or `apply`.

If you actually want the other values as well, you can use the `apply` method in the `from` clause for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  this worked, I used ''TOP 1' and it's bringing back the correct data. I'll have to do some reading on apply since am not familiar with that method. :)